Java regex how to get version from string?
А regex is required to search for a version in a row of the form:
0.6.9b-version   -    0.6.9b
v0.6.99 - 0.6.99
v01.23.97 - 01.23.97
v01.23.97a-release - 01.23.97a
v1.23.97a-release - 1.23.97a

On the left is some kind of an initial line, on the right is what you need to get.
I was confused to throw it in the configurator, but my knowledge of regular expressions was not enough
I end it on
(\d[\w.()]+?[a-z])

but it does a mirror operation, removes on the contrary what I need to leave

Match ^v?(\d+(?:\.\d+)*\p{L}?).* and replace with $1

To convert your version string to your standardized version string:
version = version.replaceFirst("v?([^-]+).*", "$1")

This removes the first optional v, keeps everything until an optional -, and removes whatever comes after that.
Use a matcher like @Malvin shows, with [] contain only valid version characters in case you need to match only version strings (among others).
To remove not only v but all non-digits,
version = version.replaceFirst("\\D*([^-]+).*", "$1")


what i need to change if i want to remove ant number of letters at start, and leave oly 1 after numbers ?
vdsd123.123.123.123ahh-sdgs       -       123.123.123.123a

This is already very helpful, but I still have some questions.
what about "and leave only 1 letter after numbers" ?

"\\D*([.\\d]+\\w?).*"

pattern: (v)?([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)*[a-z]?)(-\\w+)?
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lines = { "0.6.9b-version", "v0.6.99", "v01.23.97", "v01.23.97a-release", "v1.23.97a-release" };
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(v)?([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)*[a-z]?)(-\\w+)?");

        for (String line : lines) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(2));  // Group 2 contains the version number
            }
        }
    }
}


You can replace matches of
^.*- *

with an empty string, leaving the desired part of the string.
Demo
